# What is the goal of Captain Forever?

Tags: captain-forever

I just came across [Captain forever](http://www.captainforever.com/captainforever.php), and after playing for a little while, I'm mesmerized, but I'm not entirely sure what I'm supposed to be doing.  Do I need to stay in this area, and fight off all comers until I'm destroyed?  Do I need to *go* somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"README.TXT"

```
Help me. Help us all.                                               

The blasts aren't natural phenomena. No no no. There's no covert demolition.    
There's no invasion. There's just me and this wretched ship. Every explosion    
that rocked this sector - every station slammed from orbit, every hull torn     
apart, every... everything - was my fault.                                      

I pilot the Nemesis, and she cannot be destroyed. Her hull uses self correcting 
harmonics to realign on intrusion, so when it breaches it detonates. The Nemesis
is quickly restored but everything around her is devestated. Booters and jackers
see the blast and come hunting, and I'm floating there in a lone command module.
A chocolate coated landmine. GOTO 10.                                           

I try to avoid the boot/jackers. I try to stop the Nemesis from detonating. I   
try I try I try. But I fail. I'm failing. I need sleep. I need rest. I need     
help. Help me. I patched a remote pilot interface to this web terminal so you   
can fly the Nemesis from your browser. Keep her safe.                           

- Capt. Farbs
```

The goal appeared in readme file is to keep Nemesis(which is your spaceship) from other ships.

The actual 'goal' is to blow up other spaceships and become most powerful spaceship in the Captain Forever space. You'll meet strange X-marked spaceships after get white parts.

EDIT : there's no "ending".

Answer (score 2):

Judging from the "Flight Manual" and some limited time playing the game, the idea is to shoot down other ships and use their pieces to improve your own ship. You start with basic girders, thrusters, and weapons, and upgrade them from winning in firefights.

Comment: So that's it?  You can't *win* the game?

Comment: Hence "Forever".